# What is the probability of selecting two cards of the same suit given that you select at least one heart and one king from a modified deck?

Tags: probability

**The modified deck**:The deck consists of the red J,Q,K and Aces from a standard deck.

I tried drawing TWO tree diagrams separately, one for (H is hearts) $H$ and $\overline{H}$ and one for $K$ and $\overline{K}$. Then I summed up the desirable results from $K$ to get $\frac{7}{14}$ and from $H$, I got $\frac{11}{14}$.

Now $P = \frac{\text{H,H and all K cases}}{everything} = \frac{\frac{3}{14}\left(\frac{7}{14}\right)}{\frac{11}{14}\left(\frac{7}{14}\right)}=\frac{3}{11}$ which is so close to the answer $\frac{3}{10}$. What went wrong? And I welcome and alternate solutions

Edit 1: Question: **A deck consists of the red J,Q,K and Aces from a standard deck. What is the probability that Sally selects two cards of the same suit given that she selects at least one heart and one king?**

Comment: What is a modified deck?

Comment: I specified the modified deck "The deck consists of the red J,Q,K and Aces from a standard deck"

Comment: can you rephrase/explain the question? Namely, how many cards are we drawing?

Comment: With a deck that small, it might be simplest to just write a python script and brute force it.

Comment: @Sergio The title says "What is the probability of selecting two cards". But I'll rephrase it. Sorry for all the confusion

Comment: it says "What is the probability of selecting two cards of the same suit" you could draw 10 cards and try to find the probability that two are of the same suit for example, this works for $n$ cards drawn and don't tell about the total number of cards drawn. Moreover, you need "**at least** one  heart and one king, so this tells us we will draw more than 2 cards

Comment: What? The question says only 2 cards are dealt. Why are you drawing 10 cards?

Answer (score 1):

I can't follow your calculations, perhaps because I'm very sleepy.  Here's how I would do it.  If we draw the King of Hearts, any of the other $7$ cards works, since we already have a Heart and a King.  Otherwise, we must draw the King of Diamonds and on of the three Hearts other than the King, which make ten draws in all with a Heart and a King.

The only ones where we get two cards of the same suit are those where we draw the King of Hearts and oone of the other three hearts, so the probability of success is $\frac3{10}$

I'm guessing you counted a draw twice, probably the one with two Kings.

Comment: Excellent thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here are all the cases:

i) Both are hearts and one of them is $K$

Probability $ = \frac{1}{8} \times \frac{3}{7} + \frac{3}{8} \times \frac{1}{7} = \frac{6}{56}$

ii) Both are $K$

Probability $ = \frac{2}{56}$

iii) $K$ of heart, other is diamond ($A, Q$ or $J$)

Probability $ = \frac{1}{8} \times \frac{3}{7} + \frac{3}{8} \times \frac{1}{7} = \frac{6}{56}$

iv) $K$ of diamond, other is heart ($A, Q$ or $J$)

Probability $ = \frac{1}{8} \times \frac{3}{7} + \frac{3}{8} \times \frac{1}{7} = \frac{6}{56}$

This adds to $\frac{20}{56}$.

Your numerator is case $(i)$ and hence the desired probability $ = \frac{3}{10}$

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about cases (well actually I was trying my best to avoid doing the case bash but oh well)

Comment: You are welcome. It happens :) your approach seemed fine so I figured you may have missed a case.

Comment: Hmmm would you happen to know how I could've missed a case? I drew a simple tree diagram and I didn't consider any cases

Comment: Another way to look at it is cases where kings are missing: $\frac{30}{56}$. Then cases where king is present but heart is missing: $\frac{6}{56}$. We then subtract from $1$ and that is again $\frac{20}{56}$.

Comment: @user71207 I did not understand your last comment. Just seeing. Are you asking why it happened that cases got missed even though you drew a tree diagram?

Comment: Well I just want to know how a solution USING tree diagram or dot diagram could work in this case (it was from a dot diagram exercise). I drew to separate ones: one for Hearts and Not Hearts, and one for King and Not King. Then I only considered the outcomes where you get H and K. We want H, H and K so I multiplied those together from the two tree diagrams and put it over the rest (at least H and K)

Comment: Though I do not see the details in your question but here is what I suspect - did you eliminate duplicate cases correctly? Based on the probability you got, I guess there is a duplicate case in there.

Comment: From $H$, seems like you should have gotten $\frac{10}{14}$ instead of $\frac{11}{14}$? So there is an additional case in there somewhere.